# Selenium IDE is not showing the option in a dropdown list

Tags: selenium-ide

I have this problem:
When I click in the dropdown list when I´m recording a test, I can see the option and choose one, but, when I run the test, the click put the focus in the select, but the diferents options option are not showing. I tried it using select comand directly, and doing a click before the select too, but I don't get anything.
Thank you!!

Comment: Do you only want to see  the option or want to select too?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try to copy the Xpath / full Xpath of the element and enter it manually on the click command:
example:
Click | xpath=//somexpath